# how to create fieldset in django

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I want to make a formset with 4 forms (name, lastname, phone, address) that I want to have them in 2 groups called: 'general info' and 'optional info'. How can I use fieldset to do that? and how can I parse it?
I read some tutorial but none worked.

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label=_("name"), required=true)
    lastname= forms.CharField(label=_("lastname"), required=true)
    address= forms.CharField(label=_("address"), required=false)
    phone = forms.CharField(label=_('phone'), required=false)
```

I'm not sure whether this is true or not but I have done this:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(label=_("name"), required=true)
        lastname= forms.CharField(label=_("lastname"), required=true)
        address= forms.CharField(label=_("address"), required=false)
        phone = forms.CharField(label=_('phone'), required=false)

        class Meta:
            fieldsets = (
              ('name', {
                'fields': ('name', 'lastname')
               }),
        ('optional', {
            'fields': ('address', 'phone})
        )
```

what happens is that the json I receive is containing only the string of 'name' and 'lastname' and the others, not the value of them.
thanks

Comment: Please add some own effort and point where you fail. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @pirho tnx, added

Comment: check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets  and https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1019/  and https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/663/

Comment: @Vicmathur whatever i see is in admin page, is it important? because my page is not the admin page